# Collision Rect methods

Tags: android, surfaceview, collision, touch-event

I'm trying to move a `Bitmap` around the screen `onTouch` of a `Rect`. Of course, I don't want the Image to disappear, or go off screen, so I create a Rect for each side, top and bottom of the screen. [image: A] I apologize for my beautiful artwork.

**onTouch**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            // Left Key Touched
            if (x <= bLeftRect.right && x >= bLeftRect.left
                    && y >= bLeftRect.top && y <= bLeftRect.bottom) {

                hero.setX(hero.getX() - tileDimen);
                heroRect.set(hero.getX(), hero.getY(), hero.getX() + tileDimen, hero.getY() + tileDimen);
                if (heroRect.intersect(wallTopRect)) {
                    hero.setX(hero.getX() + tileDimen);
                } else if (heroRect.intersect(wallLeftRect)) {
                    hero.setX(hero.getX() + tileDimen);
                }

                //etc....
```

Is there a better approach, as I am going to have more objects in need of collision-rects. I was thinking maybe creating 1 "perimeter" `Rect`:

```
//Right key touched
if (perimeterRect.contains(heroRect)) {
                    hero.setX(hero.getX() + tileDimen);
                 } else {
                  //do nothing (collision) 
                 }
```

Would this be a better approach? Any advise/insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:
  Much simpler to check if heroRect is inside of perimeterRect on each `MotionEvent`, if heroRect is inside of perimeter, then check to see if heroRect collides with any other `Rect`s

**My onTouch Method:**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            // Left Key Touched
            if (x <= bLeftRect.right && x >= bLeftRect.left
                    && y >= bLeftRect.top && y <= bLeftRect.bottom) {

                hero.setX(hero.getX() - tileDimen);
                heroRect.set(hero.getX(), hero.getY(), hero.getX() + tileDimen, hero.getY() + tileDimen);

                if (!(perimeterRect.contains(heroRect))) {
                    hero.setX(hero.getX() + tileDimen);
                    heroRect.set(hero.getX(), hero.getY(), hero.getX() + tileDimen, hero.getY() + tileDimen);
                } //else if hero collides with other Rects... {
                // }

                // Up Key Touched
            } else if (x <= bUpRect.right && x >= bUpRect.left
                    && y >= bUpRect.top && y <= bUpRect.bottom) {

                hero.setY(hero.getY() - tileDimen);
                heroRect.set(hero.getX(), hero.getY(), hero.getX() + tileDimen, hero.getY() + tileDimen);

                if (!(perimeterRect.contains(heroRect))) {
                    hero.setY(hero.getY() + tileDimen);
                    heroRect.set(hero.getX(), hero.getY(), hero.getX() + tileDimen, hero.getY() + tileDimen);
                } //else if hero collides with other Rects... {
                // }

                // Right Key Touched
            } else if (x <= bRightRect.right && x >= bRightRect.left
                    && y >= bRightRect.top && y <= bRightRect.bottom) {

                hero.setX(hero.getX() + tileDimen);
                heroRect.set(hero.getX(), hero.getY(), hero.getX() + tileDimen, hero.getY() + tileDimen);

                if (!(perimeterRect.contains(heroRect))) {
                    hero.setX(hero.getX() - tileDimen);
                    heroRect.set(hero.getX(), hero.getY(), hero.getX() + tileDimen, hero.getY() + tileDimen);
                } //else if hero collides with other Rects... {
                // }

                // Down Key Touched
            } else if (x <= bDownRect.right && x >= bDownRect.left
                    && y >= bDownRect.top && y <= bDownRect.bottom) {

                hero.setY(hero.getY() + tileDimen);
                heroRect.set(hero.getX(), hero.getY(), hero.getX() + tileDimen, hero.getY() + tileDimen);

                if (!(perimeterRect.contains(heroRect))) {
                    hero.setY(hero.getY() - tileDimen);
                    heroRect.set(hero.getX(), hero.getY(), hero.getX() + tileDimen, hero.getY() + tileDimen);
                } //else if hero collides with other Rects... {
                // }

            } else {
                //button was not pressed, do nothing
            }

            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now the bitmap will not go past perimeter Rect :)

[image: After]